# Does "to protest somebody" make sense?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In the [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/protest_2),

> [intransitive, transitive] to say or do something to show that you
>   disagree with or disapprove of something, especially publicly
>
> **protest (about/against/at something)**
>
> *Students took to the streets to protest against the decision.*
>
> **protest something**
>
> *(North American English) They fully intend to protest the decision.*

My question is:

Does "**to protest somebody**" make sense?

Can we say?

*We are protesting my boss.*

*We are protesting the president.*

Comment: Perhaps ["protests *against* someone"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protests_against_Donald_Trump)?

Comment: Maybe it makes sense in a US context. I think it's a very odd expression in a UK context.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it makes sense.

> [Definition of protest](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protest)
>   transitive verb
>   3 : to make a statement or gesture in objection to • *protested the abuses of human rights*
>   (M-W)

The definition does not exclude people.

So for example, if people are marching in front of the White House holding signs with messages against the president, then it would make sense if a marcher said

> We are protesting the president.

Here are some relevant examples I found online (emphasis mine):

> - Many Americans are marking this President’s Day not by celebrating presidents past — but by **protesting the current one**. [...]
>     Organizers told am New York on Monday that some 13,000 people gathered outside Trump International Hotel at Manhattan’s Columbus Circle to **protest the president**.
>     ([‘Not My President’s Day’: Thousands Protest President Trump in Rallies Across U.S.](http://www.people.com/politics/not-my-presidents-day-protest-president-trump/))
> - The two women were among a hundred newly engaged activists assembled in Republican-heavy Lancaster County – an area that went to Trump in November by 57 percent – braving toe-freezing temperatures to **protest Trump** and the lawmaker, who was 200 yards away at a chamber of commerce breakfast.
>     ([It Takes Something Seismic to Get This Group Protesting](http://www.esquire.com/news-politics/politics/news/a53717/mennonites-protest-trump/))
> - As President Donald Trump prepared to speak before Congress, at least 100 people came to The White House to **protest him** and hear a resistance address from Rosie O'Donnell.
>     ([Rosie O'Donnell leads 'Resistance Address' outside White House](http://www.9news.com/news/politics/rosie-odonnell-leads-resistance-address-outside-white-house/416433773))
> - INDEPENDENT cinemas across the United States of America will **protest President Donald Trump** by screening George Orwell’s 1984.
>     ([Donald Trump: Guess which movie US cinemas are re-screening to protest the President?)](http://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/films/770156/President-Donald-Trump-independent-cinema-1984-film-George-Orwell-John-Hurt))

Answer (score 2):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/protest), **protest** means

> to say something forcefully or complain about something
>   to show that you disagree with something by standing somewhere, shouting, carrying signs, etc.

In British English, the first meaning is generally transitive, and the direct object is a statement of fact, for example:

> He has always protested his innocence
>   He protested that he had been treated unfairly

In British English, the second meaning is generally intransitive and it is normal to use a preposition like **about** or **against** to describe in general terms what somebody is complaining about.

> He protested that the war in Iraq was a waste of money and manpower. -*direct object is a statement of fact*
>   He protested about the war in Iraq - *preposition- general description*
>   He protested against the war in Iraq - *preposition- general description*

Clearly, plenty of people regard **Trump** as a general description of something to complain about, but **Trump** could never be regarded as a statement of fact.

So, in British English, you could say

> He protested that Trump was a racist

but you can't say

> He protested Trump

Usage in the United States is somewhat different. Looking at the entry in Merriam-Webster, you will find this definition for the transitive form:

> to make a statement or gesture in objection
>   *He protested the abuses of human rights*

Again, we have the idea of making a statement, but if you look at the associated example, you will see that the object is not a statement but a description in general terms of the issue: something that in British English would have to be linked by **about**.

Comment: Personally, I think it's dumb to say "protest the president" but it has become a pretty common thing to hear, at least in the US. When someone says "I'm protesting Trump", they're opposed to his existence, not complaining about some specific policy or complaining to him.

Comment: @ColleenV: so Trump is seen as the issue....

Comment: Sure, you could see it that way, but the distinction is pretty fine for someone learning English and I think it's confusing to say "No, protest somebody doesn't make sense." when "protest Trump" is being used all over the place lately. Maybe you could elaborate on the difference between protesting to and protesting about with some examples.